# Can we get the link in POST?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a bootstrap navbar on my website, in which a dropdown is filled with  some data from database.

Now When i click on that link,  i want to sent that data in POST to my controller. Is this possible ?

This is my dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">
    <?php
    foreach($sites as $site) {
        echo "<li>".$site->site_key."</li>";
    }
    ?>
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Updated Code :

```
 <form id="hiddenForm" method="post"   style="display: none">
          <input name="linkAddress" value="<?php echo $site->site_key; ?>">
          <input name="otherData" value="">
    </form>


<script>
      var specialLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("specialLink");
        var hiddenForm = document.getElementById('hiddenForm');


        Array.prototype.forEach.call(specialLinks, function(link) {
        link.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.addEventListener('load', function() {
                var response = req.responseText;

                //Do something with response, like change a part of the page
            });

            //Set the page to send the request to
            req.open('POST', 'recieve.php');
            //Specify that we're using URL-encoded coded parameters
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            //Send the URL-encoded POST data.
            req.send('linkAddress=' + link.href + '&otherData=' + someOtherData());
        }

    </script>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: hi why you don't use jquery by giving class or id

Comment: @FreddySidauruk i dont know how to use Jquery to get it

Comment: well where is part should post to controller, please be clear when i saw your question there is no from why now they are exist ?

Comment: @FreddySidauruk i have updated the code as per the community gave me

Comment: i have written updated code

Comment: oke let me ask you yah !
1.do you have dropdown ul li a with variable $site->site_key
2. do you want to send this variable to controller $site->site_key

answer number with yes, so i can understand

Comment: Yes I want to send it to controller

Comment: oke, help me can you ctrl+u your ul li a then copy and paste that code in pastebin.com, i will make simple demo based on your situation

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/shKdmwti

Comment: oh shit i mean like this ctrl+u please see here http://prntscr.com/a783lj i mean you should copy and paste the code i'd give circle, not your php code , duh

Comment: Okay this is it ? http://pastebin.com/gE0g1KtY

Comment: oke after see your html code, it's weird for me cause your html not look good cause inside a has 2 li ? do you mind i change the html like this http://codepen.io/sidaurukfreddy/pen/zrgJxG

Comment: Yeah okay you may change it the reason of my html is php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after long discussion, here is i get what he want to

1. He want to send variable to controller by click (I use Jquery)

so here is my [demo](http://codepen.io/sidaurukfreddy/pen/zrgJxG) based on your issue

note in that demo you need latest jquery, please see external js

so i change your html to make it easy

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="specialLink" id="54th-65hy">
            <li>54th-65hy</li>
          </a>

       <a href="#" class="specialLink" id="HT45-YT6T">
            <li>HT45-YT6T</li>              
          </a>
  </ul>
```

**Please see i put your value as id**

and this is my js

```
$( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
      var value = this.id; //get value for throw to controller
    alert(value);  

  $.ajax({
         type: "POST", //send with post
         url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/post) ?>", //for example of mine , using your controller
       data: "value=" + value, //assign the var here 
         success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
         }
    });
});
```

see the id i save into variable with name value to send to controller welcome/post

then this is the controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function post()
    {
        $value=$this->input->post('value');
    echo $value;
    }

  }
```

to make you know ajax, just comment my js in demo will be like this

```
   $( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
      var value = this.id; //get value for throw to controller
    alert(value);  

  $.ajax({
         type: "POST", //send with post
         url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/post) ?>", //for example of mine , using your controller
       data: "value=" + value, //assign the var here 
         success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
         }
    });
});
```

Edit : 
 1. make the demo become show the value first after you know it just copy and     paste js in answer into codepen
 2. in the demo i pust controller in js part
 3. please see in js file demo data: "value=" + value,

Comment: then uncomment the js, follow my instruction there

Comment: you mean in post function ? don't tested in that demo, codepen not support php test in yours !

Comment: the code is working fine by i dont get anything in post  i

Comment: Okay i wil try it then]

Comment: tell me how to just send it to post instead of alert

Comment: i have update the answer, please the js file data: "value=" + value,

Comment: $( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
      var value = this.id; //get value for throw to controller
    alert(value);  

  $.ajax({
         type: "POST", //send with post
         url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/post) ?>", //for example of mine , using your controller
       data: "value=" + value, //assign the var here 
         success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
         }
    });
});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104373/discussion-between-rajan-and-freddy-sidauruk).

Comment: what do we mean here  data: "value=" + value, //assign the var here

Comment: that name varibale will  send to the controller, i guess you already solved ? did you click check list my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could override the link's usual behavior and instead send a POST when clicked, then just supply the link's href as a parameter.

The easiest way to send the POST would probably be a hidden form set to POST, and just programatically set the form's field's then submit when someone clicks a link.

### Example

I wrote out a sample page that uses both variations to send the request:

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post Send Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Place somewhere on your page if you're using the hidden form method:
        The display needs to be none so the form doesn't show.
        Ideally, this won't use inline styling, obviously.-->
        <form id="hiddenForm" method="post" action="receive.php" style="display: none">
            <input name="linkAddress" value="">
            <input name="otherData" value="">
        </form>
        <!-- You could also programatically create the form using Javascript if you want -->

        <a class="specialLink" href="www.someaddress.com">A Link!</a>
        <a class="specialLink" href="www.someaddress.com/someSubPage">Another Link!</a>

        <script>
            var specialLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("specialLink");
            var hiddenForm = document.getElementById('hiddenForm');

            //If using a form, grab all links, and set the click handlers to fill
            // and submit the hidden form
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(specialLinks, function(link) {
                link.onclick = function(event) {
                    //Prevent the link from causing navigation. 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //Grab the link and other field
                    var linkAddress = document.querySelector('#hiddenForm [name=linkAddress]');
                    var otherDataField = document.querySelector('#hiddenForm [name=otherData]');

                    //Set the form field to the link's address
                    linkAddress.value = link.href;

                    otherDataField.value = someOtherData();

                    hiddenForm.submit();
                }
            });

            //Or via AJAX, grab all links again, but create a AJAX request instead
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(specialLinks, function(link) {
            link.onclick = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

                req.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    var response = req.responseText;

                    //Do something with response, like change a part of the page
                });

                //Set the page to send the request to
                req.open('POST', 'recieve.php');
                //Specify that we're using URL-encoded coded parameters
                req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                //Send the URL-encoded POST data.
                req.send('linkAddress=' + link.href + '&otherData=' + someOtherData());
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind, I only learned how to use the form a month ago, and AJAX in this way only a couple days ago. While I know this works, I can't speak for best practices. Also note, I'm not doing any error handling here for the sake of brevity. In reality, you should be checking the response code of the AJAX request to ensure it went through properly.

Comment: Please do post an example when u reach home so i can get better idea

Comment: @Rajan OK. Im actually using this right now to tell the server the page to return to. If you know Ajax, you could also use it, depending on what you want to do with the response.

Comment: I would like to use ajax to send the POST data to my controller here

Comment: @Rajan Stefan basically posted what I was talking about, although I was going to use Javascript.

Comment: But it does not work, When i turn on my profiler i see no post data

Comment: @Rajan Stefan's doesn't work? There may be an error in his code. I know the technique works though, but like I say, I implemented it differently.

Comment: okay i will try to debug it, but i guess i should go with ajax because what i want to do finally is change my page's content on the basis of site selected from dropdown.

Comment: can i help you rajan?

Comment: here you are giving action to that form can i do it without action>

Comment: Can you Please tell me how to do it with my code? Coz i have a Bootstrap Li in which i have the links

Comment: @Rajan Why? If that's the case, use the second option.

Comment: Okay i will try that

Comment: @Rajan You're interpreting it as php or html? I don't know why `form` wouldn't be defined. It's a standard HTML tag.

Comment: i am upadint my code please tell me where i am wrong, ]

Comment: @Rajan You're using Stefan's code. That's not a good idea for the reasons listed in the comments.

Comment: Okay so shall i just copy paste your hidden form here?

Comment: @Rajan Read through my code to understand it. I wrote both examples into the same chunk of code, so copying and pasting won't work.

Comment: I have updated the code, i am not sure what i should be writing in my code so please check it once

Comment: I passed the Sitekey in value of that input

Comment: i get this error in javascript : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: error i solved was missing a closing bracket but i dont get post yet

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: create a form to submit the the data via post**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="form.submit();">
      <?php

      foreach($sites as $site) {
        echo "<form action='index.php' method='POST'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='attribute' value='1'>";
        echo "<li>".$site->site_key."</li>";
        echo "</form>";
      }


      ?>
    </a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This will create a load of links which tell the form to submit, but also create a ton of forms, so the link won't know which form to submit.

Comment: I dont get anything in my POST here

Comment: I would have created one form, then just populated it as needed so your page doesn't explode in length.

Comment: you must change the 'index.php' to your site wich will handle the request

Comment: i get post data if i add : echo "<input type ='submit'>"; but this always show a button in my dropdown which i dont want @gabe3886

Comment: i get post data if i add : echo "<input type ='submit'>"; but this always show a button in my dropdown which i dont want @StefanSchulz

Comment: How will the form get submitted ?? @StefanSchulz

Comment: @Rajan I'm almost home. I'll have an example up within the hour.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  thanks but by that time i will home so could see your answer only tommorow

Comment: @Rajan OK, sorry. It's actually 7am here, and I went out for breakfast.

Comment: @Carcigenicate its 7:30 pm here :) please let me know how i can use ajax here to refresh my page's content on the basis of what i select from dropdown

Comment: @Rajan I'll post examples of both the form and Ajax. You may find after starting that one is more appropriate than the other.