# Ajax: the data are not sent to the php url

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

I am having trouble in uploading my database information when I click on a specific link.

The data is not sent to upload.php
myfunc is being called. The success message is shown when I click on the link.

Javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

            function myfunc(a, b)
    {
                          $.ajax({
                            url: "upload.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {"a": a, "b": b},
                            success:function() {
                             alert( "Done");
                            }
                           });
    }


        </script>
```

upload.php:

```html
if (isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])) 
    {


        $a = $_POST['a'];
        $b  = $_POST['b'];


        $query1 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET a = a + 1 where uid="'.$a.'"');                                        
        $query1->execute();

        $query2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET b = b + 1 where uid="'.$b.'"');                                        
        $query2->execute();

        if (!$query1 || !$query2)
        { 
            echo "Erreur SQL";
            exit();
        }

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you explain more, this is my answer with similiar question with you, or make simple demo in codepen or jsfildde
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578176/can-we-get-the-link-in-post/35595740#35595740

Comment: If `success()` fires then you're definitely sending something out. It doesn't look like your PHP code returns anything. It could be skipping your `if` block all together.  You should print out a message which you can capture as the first argument to your `success` function in Javascript you you can see a status.  Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab to see what your request actually sends

Comment: It seems that anything is sent... the if block is not read

Comment: Can you give me an exemple that I can copy paste bacause I have been looking for a solution for several days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check first if the data is actually being posted to upload.php? To check that:

Javascript:

```
function myfunc(a, b)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"a": a, "b": b},
    success:function(result) {
        alert(result);
        alert("Done");
    }
   });
}
```

upload.php

```
<?php

echo 'a = '.$_POST['a'] . "\n" . 'b = '.$_POST['b']; exit;

if (isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])) 
{
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b  = $_POST['b'];


    $query1 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET a = a + 1 where uid="'.$a.'"');                                        
    $query1->execute();

    $query2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET b = b + 1 where uid="'.$b.'"');                                        
    $query2->execute();

    if (!$query1 || !$query2)
    { 
        echo "Erreur SQL";
        exit();
    }
}     

?>
```

That should display in a popup the values of a and b. If those are getting displayed then that means the data is being passed to upload.php.

Comment: That's the problem. The data is not sent to upload.php.

Comment: Can you give me an exemple that I can copy paste bacause I have been looking for a solution for several days ?